# The sum of $n$ consecutive $n$th powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a very entertaining cousin of Fermat's Last Theorem which is much more accessible to human beings. At least, it's entertaining to me, and I hope you will have fun with it too.

I'm hoping that someone here can use a method I haven't thought of to produce a more elegant solution (and even a complete one). The pleasure of knowing it will greatly outweigh the embarrassment of not having found it myself!

**Cyprian's Last Theorem**

"The sum of $n$ consecutive $n$th powers is never the next $n$th power, except for $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$ and $3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 = 6^3$"

Or, to put it another way, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x-i)^{n}}=x^{n}$$ has no integer solutions for $n>3$.

In what follows, I'll use $N(n)$ to denote "the value of $x$ which is the solution to this equation".

**Modular arithmetic**

Simple modular arguments yield the following results:

- The theorem is true when $n\not\equiv{2}\pmod{16}$.
- If $n$ is even, the theorem is true when $n\equiv{3}\pmod{9}$.
- If $n$ is even, $p$ is prime and $(p-1)\vert{n}$, an argument modulo $p^2$ shows that the theorem is true when $n\equiv (p+1)l+m\pmod{p^2}$, where $l$ is an integer less than $p-1$, and $2<m<p+1$ if $l<p-2$ or $3<m<p+1$ if $l=p-2$.
- If $n$ is odd, the theorem is true when $n$ is square-free, and $n>3$.

**Numerical solutions**

Numerical experimentation pointed towards the result that $$N(n)=\frac{n}{\log2}+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{370n}+O(n^{-2})$$

This is a delightful and unexpected fact (proved by Richard Stong in answer to Problem 11324 in the Problems page of the *American Mathematical Monthly*). It allows the modular arithmetic arguments to be extended:

- Whether $n$ is even or odd, the theorem is true if $n$ is square-free and $n>3$.

**Non-square-free $n$**

The radical of $n$, $\mathrm{rad}(n)$, is the product of all the prime factors of $n$ taken once each. I'll write $a=n/\mathrm{rad}(n)$, so that $a$ is a measure of how "un-square-free" $n$ is.

Consider $\frac{N(n)}{n}$. As $n$ increases, this decreases towards $\frac{1}{\log{2}}$. $N(n)$ being an integer implies that $\frac{N(n)}{n}$ is a multiple of $\frac{1}{a}$. So as $n$ increases, $\frac{N(n)}{n}$ decreases past a number of "danger points", multiples of $\frac{1}{a}$, until no such multiple remains between it and $\frac{1}{\log{2}}$, and all danger of $N(n)$ being an integer is past.

For some $a$, such as 3, 5, 7, 13, 15 and 17, the closest danger point is quite far away from the destination, and it is hit before $n$ has increased to a level which could (according to modular arguments) make $N(n)$ an integer. So the theorem is proved for those values of $a$.

For other values of $a$, "$n$ high enough for integer $N(n)$ to be possible" happens before all the danger points are passed, so some checking by hand is needed.

**Continued fractions**

This is ultimately the most hopeful prospect for getting a general proof, but there are still some sticking points.

The Stong formula can be doubled to $$2N(n)=\tfrac{2}{\log2}n+3+\tfrac{1}{185}n^{-1}+O(n^{-2})$$
If we approximate $\frac{2}{\log{2}}$ with a fraction $\frac{m}{n}$, this becomes $$2N(n)=m+(\tfrac{2}{\log2}-\tfrac{m}{n})n+3+\tfrac{1}{185}n^{-1}+O(n^{-2})$$
and if the approximation is really accurate, it has a chance of cancelling out the $O(n^{-2})$ term and leaving $2N(n)=m+3$, which, if $m$ is odd, gives an integer $N(n)$, disproving the theorem.

So it all boils down to a continued fraction expansion of $\frac{2}{\log{n}}$. Find a large term, because truncating before it means an exceptionally accurate approximation. The term has to be in an odd and not an even position, and the numerator $m$ of the truncated fraction has to be odd.

I have looked at the first 1000 terms of the continued fraction. There are 8 large terms, but 3 of them are in an even position and 4 of the others give an even numerator. Truncating the continued fraction before the 632rd term gives an odd numerator, but applying a modular argument modulo $79^2$ shows that $N(n)$ cannot be an integer.

The denominator of the approximation reached after 1,000 terms of the continued fraction is $n=9.55\times{10^{514}}$.

**Conclusion and questions**

So apart from the various modular and square-free and almost-square-free $n$ for which the theorem is proved, it is also proved for all $n<9.55\times{10^{514}}$. Which isn't very far when you're on a journey to infinity.

**Question:** Is there some terribly simple other method I have not tried, which yields an instant proof without all this palaver?

**Question:** Can some of these methods be refined - perhaps (particularly) sharpening the asymptotic formula for $N(n)$?

**Question:** Please tell me that this is not a standard result on page 6 of Hardy & Wright!